# True/false with justification. $A ∈ M_{n}(K)$, and for any $v ∈ M_{n×1}(K)$, $ Av = 0$, so $A = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $A ∈ M_n(K)$. If for all $v ∈ M_{n×1}(K)$, $Av = 0$, then $A = 0$. True or false?

Mark scheme states Yes because for all $ 1 ≤ i ≤ n$, we take

$$v = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\1\\\vdots\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} $$

with 1 in i-th position, so Av is the i-th column of A. So all columns of A are 0 and A = 0. My question is why is 1 in position i? As in where did they get the one from. I feel like i'm missing something or forgetting something about linear algebra when i do this question because i don't understand the explanation at all. D:

Comment: Just multiply $A$ by $v_i$ and carry on the computation.

Comment: Do you disagree that $Av$ is the $i$th column of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nature of matrix multiplication dictates that $Av=v_1\vec{a}_1+\cdots+v_n\vec{a}_n$ where $\vec{v}=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)^T$ and the vectors $\vec{a}_1,\cdots,\vec{a}_n$ are the columns of $A$. The matrix $A$ is zero iff all its columns are zero, and we've just seen that matrix multiplication has that $Ae_i=\vec{a}_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector.

So that's that.